# is possible to add extra properties in a many to many relationship?

Tags: grails

I am creating a many to many relationship between Sale and Detail domain classes, I understand from [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) that Grails maps a many-to-many using a join table at the database level.

what I need to know is that is possible to add extra properties to this association and get something like this

```
sale_id ++++ detail_id ++++ quantity ++++ total
1            1              5             50
1            2              9             45
```

I hope I was able to explain my self

Thank for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the join table to store columns in addition to the two foreign keys, you need to decompose the many-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships, e.g.

```
class Sale {
  static hasMany = [saleDetails: SaleDetail]
}

class Details {
  static hasMany = [saleDetails: SaleDetail]
}

class SaleDetail {
  static belongsTo = [sale: Sale, detail: Detail]
  Integer quantity
  Integer total
}
```

Comment: Is good to see how flexible could be Hibernate/GORM, i would like to find this kind of information in documentation